# do ios apps using parse framework need to be upgraded for iOS7?

Tags: ios7, parse-platform

I am seeing a lot of strange crashes concerning parse object saving.  Does my app need a parse library that is targeted for iOS 7?

I didn't receive any correspondence that i needed to upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like they did.  Just delete the parse.framework folder in your and replace it with the latest from parse

Comment: Or you can clean your project, delete derived data after set your project target for iOS7, it will work :)